# Bartle, Introduction to Real Analysis (2011 4 ed), Section 2.4, Exercise 5, p 45.

Tags: real-analysis

So, I'm working on the this problem and I got the first half done. I'm not sure about the second part and need help. Here is the problem:

> 5. Let S be a set of nonnegative real numbers that is bounded above and let $T:=\{x² : x ∈ S\}$. Prove that if $u = \sup S$, then $u² = \sup T$.

So, we need to show that u² = sup T by:

1. $t ≤ u², ∀ t ∈ T$
2. $∀ ε > 0, ∃ t ∈ T$ so that $u² - ε < t$.

Proof: Assume that u = sup S is true. Then,

1. Since u = sup S, it follows that s ≤ u. Squaring both sides, s² ≤ u². And since t = s², it follows that t ≤ u².

---

So, here is where I got stuck. I don't know how to construct the ε so that in the end I get u² - ε < t. I saw a solution to this problem where they suggested constructing ε/(2u) > 0, but it just didn't make sense to me. You can see the solution [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:wdcnWX840y8J:math.osu.edu/%7Edavis.3929/Math4547Analysis1/lecture7/solution.tex+&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon >0$, you want to find $t\in T$ such that $$u^2-t<\varepsilon$$

Now, you know $t=s^2$ for some $s\in S$; so you want $$u^2-s^2<\varepsilon$$ for some $s\in S$. This means we want to find $s\in S$ so that $(u-s)(u+s)<\varepsilon$.

Now note $u$ is a fixed positive number (we can assume it is positive, else all elements of $S$ and hence all elements of $T$ are zero, since every element of $S$ is greater or equal to zero). Moreover, we know that for any $s\in S$, $s\leqslant u$, since $u$ is the *supremum* of $S$. This in turn means that $$\tag 1 u+s\leqslant u+u=2u$$ for any $s\in S$.

Since $u$ is the supremum of $S$, given $\dfrac{\varepsilon}{4u} >0$ there exists $s\in S$ for which $$\tag 2 u-s<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{4 u}$$ Consider now the element $s^2\in T$. Then using $(1)$ and $(2)$ we get $$u^2-s^2=(u-s)(u+s)<\frac{\varepsilon}{4u}(u+s)\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{4u}2u=\frac \varepsilon 2<\varepsilon$$

Since you already showed $u^2$ is an upper bound of $T$, the above shows it is the least upper bound of $T$, as we wanted.

Comment: Sorry, Pedro, but the definition says that it has to be u² - ε < t, not u² − t < ε.

Comment: @user129360 $u^2-\varepsilon <t$ is the same as $u^2-t <\varepsilon$.

Comment: OK, I started to follow you how you got (u - s)(u + s) < ε. Then, how did you conclude that (u - s) < ε/(4u)?

Comment: @user129360 Given $\varepsilon>0$ I picked s in S so that holds using the definition of sup S.

Comment: I'm still confused, Pedro. Sorry. Please, could you make it more clear? I see how you went from u² - ε < t, to u² - t < ε, to u² - s² < ε, to (u - s)(u + s) < ε. But then you conclude with u - s < ε/(4u). How did you get there?

Comment: @user129360 Remember that $u=\sup T$, hence the choice of $s$ is legal.

Comment: u = sup S, not sup T.

Comment: @user129360 Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: I'm still not seeing how if u - s < e, then u - s < e/(4u). I'm not sure that this inequality is true.

Comment: @user129360 You don't choose $s$ such $u-s<\varepsilon$ but _directly_ such that $u-s<\varepsilon/4u$, i.e. in this case your 'epsilon' is $\varepsilon/4u$.

Comment: How do you arrive at that e/(4u)? What assures you that given u - s < e, u - s < e/(4u)? I followed his reasoning in the proof and when I got to the part where he says that (u - s)(u + s) < (e/2)(u + s)/(u + u) I got stuck. After reducing both sides by u + s, we get to u - s < e/(4u). How is this true?

Comment: @user129360 Your difficulty is typical: read again my comments. If you succeed, you take a big step in understanding analysis.

Comment: So, can neither of you explain to me why it makes sense that (u-s)(u+s)<(e/2)(u + s)/(u + u), I'm still confused?

Comment: @user129360 I have rewritten the proof. Make an effort and read it carefully.

Comment: One more question, Pedro: How did you figure to pick e/(4u)? I follow your proof. (I even figured out the one you written earlier). It is crystal clear and it is by far better than what was written on that other university site. But I just want to know how should I in the future figure out to pick an s so that u - s < e/(4u)? Where did that e/(4u) come from? It seems to me that there was some work done outside of this proof on a scratch paper and I would like to see that to learn that ingenuity. Thanks.

Comment: @user129360 Indeed, we usually work in scratch paper and then translate our ideas formally! One also does reverse engineering. For example, $$\begin{align}u^2-s^2&<\varepsilon\\(u-s)(u+s)&<\varepsilon\\u-s&< \frac{\varepsilon}{u+s}\\& \leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{u+u} \\&=\frac{\varepsilon}{2u}\end{align}$$

Not we "only" get $\leqslant$; and we simply change $2$ to $4$ to get $\leqslant \varepsilon/2<\varepsilon$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! I appreciate all of your help, as I understand that your time is worth a lot. May God bless you and your family.

Comment: @user129360 No problem. If you think this answer helped you (and as there are no other answer) you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark $\checkmark$ next to the votes tally.

Comment: Done. (I didn't know how this works since I am new here).

Comment: This proof is simply wrong. The person who answered the question, and Tony have pulled 4u out of their hats and failed to explain why. I'm certain user129360 gave up and decided your answer was correct without understanding it.

Comment: @AndrewGrant Please stick to a civil tone when commenting. Could you point out anything that you find unclear?

Comment: Nothing is unclear to me. You have provided a false proof, and the handwaved away the person who asked the initial question. If you do not understand how to prove this, you should not have commented in the first place. Please refer to my answer below for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need $\epsilon$? Here's Bartle's partial solution.

> If $x∈S$, then $0≤x≤u$, so that $x^2 ≤u^2$ which implies $\sup T ≤u^2$. If t is any
> upper bound of T, then $x∈S$ implies $x^2 ≤t$ so that $x≤\sqrt t$. It follows that $u≤
> \sqrt t$, so that $u^2 ≤t$. Thus $u^2 ≤\sup T$.

Answer (score 0):

$ \forall t \in{T}, \exists s\in{S}, t = s^{2}$

also, since $ U = sup(S), \forall{s}\in{S}, U \ge s$, thus $U^2 \ge s^2$

Then, $U^2 \ge s^2 = t$, therefore $U^2$ is an Upper Bound of $T$

Now suppose that $U^2 \ne sup(T)$, then $\exists V$ such that $V \lt U^2$, and $\forall{t}\in{T}, V \ge t$

We now know that $U^{2} \gt V \ge t \ge 0, \forall{t}\in{T}$

Thus $U \gt \sqrt{V} \ge \sqrt{t} \ge 0$

Thus $U \gt \sqrt{V} \ge s \ge 0$, since $\sqrt{t}$ maps to an $s$

This says that $\sqrt{V}$ is an upperbound of $S$, which is less than $U$

However, since $U = sup(S)$, no such $\sqrt{V}$ exists, and $\therefore \nexists V$ where $V\lt U^2$ and $\forall{t}\in{T}, V \ge t$

Finally, since $U^2$ is an upperbound of $T$ and no lesser upperbounds exist, $U^2 = sup(T)$